# "Upgrade current target for ipad" is grayed out (disabled)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal-code

I'm trying to create a universal iPhone/iPad app using this method: http://www.enscand.com/roller/enscand/entry/ready_for_ipad which is also described all over the web. My problem is that the "Upgrade current target for iPad" line is grayed out and doesn't appear at all when I right click the target.

I'm working on an app that I inherited from someone, and have tried this with an app that I wrote entirely myself (no problems on that one). And yes, I'm sure that I'm selecting the target.

Just wondering if anyone has any insight into what checks are being run that would cause this option to be unavailable.

Comment: Sadly, I'm having the same issue. I can't figure out what is causing it to not work on this project. and yes, I have the target selected too.

Comment: For the record, no answers posted here have worked for me as of 2010-07-07. In the end (several weeks ago) I just manually made new "-iPad.xib" files where necessary and linked to them conditionally using

"if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)"

... a pretty rough route to go but it did the trick. Still curious as to why I wasn't able to do it the built-in way on this project (it works for me on other projects). Thanks for everyone's help here.

Answer (score 7):

It took me a while to realize that you have to have a target selected before the menu item will become enabled.

Comment: Thanks but yes, I've selected the target. I'm able to get it to work on another app.

Comment: Did you select it by click it in Groups & Files on left or just the drop down at the top? You have to select it in Groups & Files

Answer (score 3):

I figured out that you have to select the target from the window on the left "Group & Files" for that "Upgrade Current target for ipad" to show.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. After upgrading first target just rename Resources~iPad group in Groups&Files (e.g. to ResourcesFirstTarget~iPad). After that you can upgrade your other targets with "Upgrade Current Target For iPad".

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem because I was trying to do it with the xib file selected, not the item under the the 'Targets' folder.

Answer (score 1):

I just found that my project was set to "iPhone" for Distribution, but it was still set to "iPhone/iPad" for Debug. After switching to "iPhone" for Debug also, the option to convert to a Universal app became available.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this is an actual solution but I solved this problem by selecting the target, going to "Project" and setting the Active Build Configuration to "Release". Update Current Target for IPad then became enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the "Resources-iPad" group and voila - the "Update Current Target for iPad" became enabled.

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately - thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, what I did to solve it was the normal thing:
 - select target in Groups and Files
 - (i.e change it from 'iPhone/iPad' to 'iPhone').

and it was grayed out...
 - so I've cleaned the project (Build/Clean All targets)

It solved my problem, so I advise you to after make some changes that supposing would made it work, to clean the project afterwards!

Hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the same problem but can upgrade if I right click the target rather than using the menu item.

Further more I've just realised that the menu item does become ungrayed out if you select the target in Groups & Files not in the drop down at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this post is still active.
In project info, take a look at "Architecture", if there's more than one entry, the "Upgrade target for ipad" is greyed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Leonardo. In the project info I have "Standard (armv6 armv7)" as the value for "Architectures", "Build Active Architecture Only" unchecked and "armv6 armv7" for "Valid Architectures". Is this the place you're talking about? I tried changing a few of these values around but still didn't see a change to "Upgrade target for iPad"

Answer (score 0):

Set you app to target iPhone in both the Project->Edit Project Settings: All Configurations
and in the side menu, where you right click the target ->Get Info same type of menu.

To be able to click the "Upgrade to Ipad(...)" you have to click and select the target. Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by right clicking on the target -> get info -> build, and changing the targeted device family from iphone/ipad to iphone.